# Add multiple swing/awt shapes to frame

Tags: java, swing, awt

Ive created a game of Craps which is a dice based game. Ive created my game logic but am trying to implement a GUI. Ive created my Dice and Dice Component for both dice. If i add my Dice to the frame one at a time they both work, but as soon as i try and add both to the frame at the same time and run my Craps game, the frame is empty.

CrapsGame code:

```
package crapsgame;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;


public class CrapsGameTester 
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Craps-Game");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;

    frame.setSize(FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH);

    CrapsGame game = new CrapsGame();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(panel);

    Dice1Component dice1 = new Dice1Component(6);
    Dice2Component dice2 = new Dice2Component(6);
    panel.add(dice1);
    panel.add(dice2);

    String message = game.doFirstRoll();
    System.out.println(message);

    while(!game.isOver())
    { 
        message = game.rollAgain();
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    if(game.isWon())
        System.out.println("You win, big man!");
    else
        System.out.println("Loser ...");

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Dice1 code:

```
package crapsgame;

import java.awt.*;

public class Dice1 
{
int sides;
int xCoord = 150;
int yCoord = 130;

public Dice1(int s)
{
    sides = s;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param g2 Graphics2D object used by draw method
 */
public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
{
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fillRect(xCoord, yCoord, 100, 100);
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    switch (sides)
    {
        case 1:
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 40, yCoord + 40, 20, 20);
            break;
        case 2:
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 15, yCoord + 15, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 65, yCoord + 65, 20, 20);
            break;
        case 3:
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 15, yCoord + 15, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 40, yCoord + 40, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 65, yCoord + 65, 20, 20);
            break;
        case 4:
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 15, yCoord + 15, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 15, yCoord + 65, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 65, yCoord + 15, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 65, yCoord + 65, 20, 20);
            break;
        case 5:
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 15, yCoord + 15, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 15, yCoord + 65, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 65, yCoord + 15, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 65, yCoord + 65, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 40, yCoord + 40, 20, 20);
            break;
        case 6: 
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 20, yCoord + 20, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 20, yCoord + 45, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 20, yCoord + 70, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 60, yCoord + 20, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 60, yCoord + 45, 20, 20);
            g2.fillOval(xCoord + 60, yCoord + 70, 20, 20);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Dice1Component code:

```
package crapsgame;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Dice1Component extends JComponent
{
private int sides;

public Dice1Component(int s)
{
    sides = s;
}

public void setSide(int s)
{
    sides = s;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    Dice1 dice1 = new Dice1(sides);
    dice1.draw(g2);
}
}
```

I read that to add more than one component to a frame you must use a JPanel but this doesn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't draw both dice onto the same component? Also I wouldn't create the Dice inside the `paintComponent` method. Keep it as a class member. Have two class members, one for each Dice. You can have setter for each Dice. If you plan on having a lot of Dices, then maybe you can create a `Map` of Dices, and access each one by key. But generally, I would use just _one_ drawing surface.

Comment: Yep, as @peeskillet: consider making Dice a logical class that knows how to draw itself but not a GUI class, not a class that extends a Swing component. Consider creating a drawing JPanel that draws all dice, and avoid creating objects and variables inside of paintComponent. You don't have control over when or if that method will be called, and so no program logic should go inside of it, just paining code.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues (in addition to those mentioned in comments), but these should make the code work:

- You should override the preferred size in `Dice1Component` so that the layout manager can
   reserve it the correct space

  ```
  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(100, 100);
  }
  ```
- remove `xCoord` and `yCoord` from `Dice1`. The coordinates used are relative to the component, so a large offset will try to draw outside the component area
- Take a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) how you should create and access components only in the event dispatch thread.